# NestJs one Post request with relation

Tags: nestjs

In my NestJs app I have two entities: `person.entity.ts` and `property.entity.ts`, the two are connected with OneToMany relation. I have created DTOs for both person and property.

The owning side of the relation is defined in Person like this:

```
  @JoinColumn()
  @OneToMany(
    (type) => PersonProperties,
    (personProperties) => personProperties.person,
    { cascade: ['insert', 'update'] },
  )
  personProperties: PersonProperties[];
```

My Controller for posting new Person looks like this:

```
 @Post()
  async create(@Body() createPersonDto: CreatePersonDto) {
    return this.personService.create(createPersonDto);
  }
```

For validation I am using Global ValidationPipes as below:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      transform: true,
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true,
      },
    }),
  );
```

How should I modify my code so I can post (and validate) a Person with their properties with a single Request? Isn't this going to include one DTO inside another?

Answer (score 0):

What you must use are Pipes [Read more about it](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes)

In your case, a Validation Pipe is required to validate the incoming request against your DTO.

Pipes are used inside a controller, though you can read about creating custom pipes inbuilt `ValidationPipe` would satisfy your needs for now.
**METHOD 1**

```
 @Post()
  async create(@Body(ValidationPipe) createPersonDto: CreatePersonDto) {
    return this.personService.create(createPersonDto);
  }
```

**METHOD 2**

```
  @Post()
    @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
          async create(@Body() createPersonDto: CreatePersonDto) {
            return this.personService.create(createPersonDto);
          }
```

Both methods essentially do the same thing. It takes your Body request object and validates it against your defined DTO.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but actually it does not answer my question, please note that I do use ValidationPipe as a global Pipe. What I am getting confused here is that I essentially have two DTOs that are posted together, one for the Person and one for the Property.

Comment: can you show some code or be more specific with what you are trying to achieve. I don't think I completely understand what you want to do.

Comment: If I am not wrong what you intend to do is you want to validate the personProperties against a ```person properties``` DTO ?? Is it so?

Comment: That's correct, which is posted together with the POST /person REST request. Quite a common requirement I guess.

Comment: Have you tried using a separate validation pipe?? ```...@Body('personProperties' , ValidationPipe) personProperties, @Body()..) 
This first checks into your body for personProperties and matches it against your personProperties Dto

Comment: There is only one Body object in an HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a composite DTO object as follows:

```
export class CreatePersonWithPropertiesDto {
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => CreatePersonDto)
  neuron: CreatePersonDto;

  @IsOptional()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => CreatePersonPropertiesDto)
  personProperties?: CreatePersonPropertiesDto[];
}
```

and then adjust the controller to expect the composite DTO:

```
@Post()
  async create(@Body() createPersonWithPropertiesDto: CreatePersonWithPropertiesDto) {
    return this.personService.create(createPersonWithPropertiesDto);
  }
```